# Does an angular component ever destroy when it is subscribed to router change event once?

Tags: angular

In a specific route I am loading a component which is subscribed to router.events to detect any route change in that component (like queryparams). When I go to different routes which load different components, still the first component's router.event is called even though the ngOnDestroy life cycle hook is called on that first component before loading the new component.My question is as the ngOnDestroy is called that means that first component should destroy.Then why still the subscribed router.events is called in every route change.

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.applicationItemIdChange = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
            if (this.applicationItemId && this.applicationItemIdChange && this.applicationItemIdChange !== this.applicationItemId) {
                this.ngOnInit();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have a memory leak in your program. The `subscription` to `this.router.events` would be almost a never-ending subscription. So once you have your component demounted, you should explicitly `unsubscribe` from it.

```
this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.applicationItemIdChange = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    if (this.applicationItemId && this.applicationItemIdChange && this.applicationItemIdChange !== this.applicationItemId) {
      this.ngOnInit();
    }
  }
});
```

Here, we stored the `Subscription` in a property.

And then in `ngOnDestroy`:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

We manually `unsubscribe` from the `Subscription`

Answer (score 1):

the reason for that is, you are still subscribing to the events, although your component is destroyed.

So either you need to keep reference to `subscription`s and `unsubscribe` from them (as @siddAjmera answer)

or you can use this pattern to unsubscribing multiple subscription without defining multiple variables.

```
class mycomp implements OnDestroy {

  private unsubscribeAll : Subject<Any> = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.unsubscribeAll.next();
     this.unsubscribeAll.complete();
  }

  foo() {
     this.router.events
     .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll)
     )
     .subscribe(...)    


     observable1
     .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll)
     )
     .subscribe(...)

  }

  bar() {
     observable2
     .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll)
     )
     .subscribe(...)
  }

}
```